# is there any way to know the url of telegram post photo using telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

im using python and telethon to get messages..
I can download the message photos but i dont want to store and download.
I want to know the url of the photo to access it any time later using that.
is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extension to @tashakori's answer

For channels that have no username set (I've seen a few), it is `https://t.me/c/channel_id/message_id`

eg.

```py
async def main():
    # TODO setup client etc.
    # this channel id was obtained from using something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62849271/8608146
    channel = await client.get_entity(-1001006503122)
    async for message in client.iter_messages(channel, reverse=True):
        # channel.id and the above -100.. id are not same
        # this channel.id looks like 1006503122
        print("message URL", f"https://t.me/c/{channel.id}/{message.id}")
```

Also note: These links are accessible only to users who are joined in the channel, of course.

There's also the `message.chat_id` property which returns the -100...

Answer (score 6):

telegram APIs won't give you direct URL to media files of posts. but, as a workaround, take a look at the new feature that Telegram has added to its website a few months ago:

you can see posts of public channels in the web just by typing URLs with this pattern:
https://t.me/"channel-username"/"post-No"

(e.g. https://t.me/gizmiztel/2350)

this way you can parse the DOM and find the direct URL to each media file.

Note: you may need a separate method for each type of files to extract files' URLs.