# How to get a telegram private channel id with telethon

Tags: python, telegram, channel, telethon

Hi can't figure out how to solve this problem, so any help will be really appreciated.
I'm subscribed to a private channel. This channel has no username and I don't have the invite link (the admin just added me).
Since I use this channel at work, to speed up the things I want to process the messages posted on the channel using Telethon.

The core of the program is:

```
@events.register(events.NewMessage(chats = my_private_channel))
async def handler(event):
    
        #do things
```

The problem is that I am not able to filter the messages coming to that specific channel id. I get the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "0123456789"
```

I have tried different technique to obtain my channel Id but the error is always the same. In particular:

1. The channel is private so it has no username ("@blablabla")
2. I have no invite link
3. I have tried to process all incoming messages until the admin sent a message on the channel, print sender information and get the value from the "ID" key
4. I have tried to use telegram web and get the ID from the url (also adding -100 in front of it)

But when I put the ID in the parameter *chats*, I get always the error reported above.

Thanks in advance,
Have a nice day

Answer (score 10):

if you have access to the channel, then it's shown in your chat list.

You have to loop through your chats checking their titles and then store the desired chat in a variable:

```py
my_private_channel_id = None
my_private_channel = None

async for dialog in tg.client.iter_dialogs():
    if dialog.name == "private chat name":
        my_private_channel = dialog
        my_private_channel_id = dialog.id
        break

if my_private_channel is None:
    print("chat not found")
else:
    print("chat id is", my_private_channel_id)
```

Than you can filter messages sent to my_private_channel.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked, and is also a good solution to keep track of all joined channels and chats. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can print all the dialogs/conversations that you are part of.
also you need to remove -100 prefix from the id you got like: `-1001419092328 = 1419092328 (actual ID)`

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events


client = TelegramClient("bot", API_ID, API_HASH)

client.start()
print(" Connected")


@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def my_event_handler(event):
    
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
        print(dialog.name, 'has ID', dialog.id) # test ID -1001419092328



client.run_until_disconnected()
```

if you want to listen to a specific channel, you can use `channel_id=1419092328`. you will only receive messages that are broadcasted to it:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel



print(f" Connecting...")
client = TelegramClient("bot", API_ID, API_HASH)

client.start()
print(" Connected")


@client.on(events.NewMessage(PeerChannel(channel_id=1419092328)))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    msg = event.text    

    print(f"[M] {msg}")


client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't join a private channel without the invite link, nor can you get any information about it. It's private, as the name implies.

Comment: Yes, but I am subscribed to that channel. On my Telegram app I can see al the messages because the admin added me. I can also read all the messages via Telethon, the only thing I am not able to do is to filter the messages passing the id in the *chats* parameter to the event.NewMessage function.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to join the channel if is public using this code:

```
channel = await client.get_entity('telegram.me/' + channel_username)
print(channel.id) # here will print your id without -100
```